# Python - Pandas groupby agg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a simple `dataframe` (df) like shown below:

```
index Job  Person 
1     j1   Cathy
2     j2   Mark
3     j3   Cathy
4     j4   Steve
5     j5   Cathy
```

I would like to convert the above `dataframe` as:

```
Person CountJob  JobDetails
Cathy     3      j1;j3;j5
Mark      1      j2
Steve     1      j4
```

I can partially solve this using `groupby` :

```
final = df.groupby('Person').agg(
        CountJob=pd.NamedAgg(column='Job',aggfunc="count"),
        )
```

I am struggling to get the format for the last column '`JobDetails`'. I am guessing I can use the `lambda` function but I just don't know how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby('Person').agg(CountJob=('Job','count'),
                         JobDetails=('Job',';'.join)
                        )
```

Comment: how to handle 'null values' in the .join section?

Comment: Do a drop a before join

Comment: I kept getting error when using 'dropna()'. Maybe my syntax was wrong. I ended up converting the entire df to str.. df = df.astype(str) and then ran the groupby.. what's the syntax for dropna..

Comment: @CodeMaster try `('Job', lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna())`. Or `df.dropna('Job').groupby(...)`